# Not seeing class in root in .NET Core console app

Tags: c#, console-application, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I created a new console app targeting .NET Core 1.1 in Visual Studio 2017 and added a very simple class which is directly in the root.

[image]

```
public class TestClass
{
   public string SomeText { get; set; }
}
```

I can't seem to use/reference this class in my Main method. The intellisense just doesn't see it at all.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:
All of a sudden, it started to work. I did nothing to fix the issue. I think this is related to Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Are they in the same namespace? Does a light bulb show up when you place your cursor on the TestClass error?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same namespace and I don't see any errors of any kind. I just get the regular message that indicates the TestClass is not found, am I missing a using directory, etc.

Comment: Saw that too.  If your VS2017 install is anything like mine then you need to keep Task Manager handy so you can see what is burning core.  It gives the installed anti-malware product a major workout, this does cause very long random delays.  And yes, very noticeable in a first kick-the-tires .NETCore project, those red squigglies take quite a while to disappear again.  I just disabled it for now, life's too short, got it on my to-do list.

Comment: I do find other IntelliSense issues (like switching among .NET Standard versions). So if possible, switch to Build Only in Error List.